# Минимальный нечетный элемент массива

Tags: javascript

Напишите функцию minOdd, которая принимает массив в качестве аргумента и возвращает минимальный нечетный элемент массива. Если массив не содержит нечетных элементов или массив пустой, вернуть undefined.Используйте в решении цикл. Не разрешается использование метода Math.min().

я написал так но не получается

```js
function minOdd(arr){                                                                
    let min = 99999                                                                      
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){                                               
        if(arr[i] < min && arr[i] % 2 !== 0){                                                              
            min = arr[i]                                                         
        }                                                                                             
    }
    return arr.length === 0  ? undefined : min
}
```

Comment: "но не получается"  --- что именно? подробнее

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе.

Comment: здравствуйте. но показывает что  ответ не правильный .

Comment: ну допустим, минимальный элемент в массиве будет 100001. Что выдаст этот код?

Comment: При каких даннных ответ неправильный? всегда? или когда? какой именно неправильный ответ показаывает? А что ожэидается при тех данных, когда не правильный ответ?

Comment: такая ошибка выходит                                                                                                                 Функция возвращает для аргумента [12,16,2] верный результат undefined
AssertionError: expected 10000 to equal undefined

Comment: Ну вот. Запусти свой код на этих данных и посмотри на результат. Это же первое, что нужно сделать!

Comment: спасибо за вашу помощь. благодаря вам я решил эту задачу. спасибо ребята